# jquery datepicker set initial date

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I need to set the initial date on jquery-ui datepicker **initialization**, so i tried with **defaultDate** field:

```
$('#first').datepicker({
    defaultDate: '12/04/2018',
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
});
```

but no luck: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8w8v9/3437/)

according to the [API](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-defaultDate) for *defaultDate* i can use:

> a string in the format defined by the dateFormat option, or a relative
>   date

so, what i'm missing? is it a jquery bug or what?

PS: i know i can setDate **after** initialization:

```
$('#second').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
}).datepicker("setDate", '12/04/2018');
```

but that's not what i need. Any idea?

Comment: downvoters, can you add some comment to explain yourselves?

Comment: You say it doesn't work, yet your fiddle seems to be working absolutely fine for me in Chrome.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i'm using Chrome too and as you can see on [this screenshot](https://imgur.com/z9ESW6a) the first datepicker is not working

Comment: `defaultDate` is select default date to DatePicker Dialog not set that date to Textbox

Comment: Your fiddle works absolutely fine. Please note that `defaultDate` will not set the date in the input field but only highlights the date when the calendar is opened. From the docs - `Set the date to highlight on first opening if the field is blank.` whereas `setDate` sets the date in the input field.

Comment: @PhaniKumarM ok so there's no init option to set a date in the input field? that should be pretty basic, isn't it?

Comment: `#first` is an input field, can't you just set it's value? (EDIT: just noticed @nebojsanebojsa answered with the same suggestion)

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca it is a backend function and i can only return an object with datepicker options, so i can't directly act on DOM elements

Comment: As has been mentioned above, the `defaultDate` only sets the default option shown in the picker. It does not set the value in the input. To do that you can use `val()` or the datepicker's own `setDate()` method. Your previos comment makes no sense, as if you can run the JS code you've specified in the question then you can 'directly act on DOM elements'

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan the code i provided was just an example to make a point. As i specified in OP setting `val()` or using `setDate` after initialization is **not** an option for me (otherwise i wouldn't ask), i just thought there was a parameter to init the datepicker in the same way the `setDate` does

Comment: and still don't get the downvoters, but whatever

Answer (score 4):

You can add a value to input field, and it will act like `defaultDate` and `setDate` at the same time

```
$('#some_input_element').val('12/04/2018').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
});
```

I have updatet your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8w8v9/3439/) as `fourth` input element